# Undefined variable in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, undefined

I have the following code inside a button-click-function

```
var ItemID2;

$.get("http://localhost/tddd27/index.php/json/Products?ItemName="+thisID, 
          function(data){
             ItemID2=data[0].ItemID;
            },"json");

console.log(ItemID2);
```

after I click the button I see in the console that `ItemID2` is undefined. If I use `console.log(data[0].ItemID)` inside the get-function I see the correct value. I think that the problem is that the execution of the function continues but Ajax has not yet retrieve the value of `ItemID2`. Any idea how can I fix that?

Comment: AJAX what means first 'A'?

Comment: Ajax is Asynchronous. You can fix it, but i suggest instead coding around it. Fixing it means making the browser look broken.

Comment: `console.log` executes before the ajax call has finished.

Comment: Can we please just close these as duplicates? This is asked like 30 times a day. Seriously, when this question comes up, don't vote, don't comment, don't answer. Just cast your close votes.

Comment: Please, if a moderator is here, just close my useless question. I got it.

Answer (score 2):

> I think that the problem is that the execution of the function continues but Ajax has not yet retrieve the value of ItemID2.

You are right, it's an asynchronous function. You have to resume your program flow to the request's callback.

Answer (score 2):

**A**-JAX is **A**-synchronous.

That is why there is a callback function.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
var ItemID2;

$.get("http://localhost/tddd27/index.php/json/Products?ItemName="+thisID, 
          function(data){
             ItemID2=data[0].ItemID;
             console.log(ItemID2);
            },"json");
```